# Thymeleaf th:href get other input field value?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is my form, with input field email & password

```
<form class="form-signin" th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

I want to try Thymeleaf `th:href` to send get request with parameter,

here is my code:

```
<a href="#" th:href="@{/user/forgot_password{email}(email=$(inputEmail).val())}" class="forgot-password"> Forgot the password? </a>
```

My Spring-Boot controller as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgot_password", params = {"email!="}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody RespCommon forgotPassword(
    @RequestParam(value = "email", required = true) String email) {
    userService.forgotPassword(email);
    return new RespCommon(ResultCode.SUCCESS, "Send forget password mail succeed");
}
```

But it seems not working, can some share how to get other input field value, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a link (and hence a `GET` method) for restoring a password doesn't look as good idea for me. It's possible that browser or e-mail client will follow it, for example.

Instead I suggest to use a form (with a POST method) that looks like a link. You can put the e-mail in the `hidden` field and add `btn btn-link` classes to a submit button. To populate e-mail value, you can export value from the controller with `Model.addAttribute()`.

Comment: Yes, I also agree with Slava Semushin ... email is a confidential issue that should be encrypted for any external get request for example 'unsubscribe email' link. Even You should use a form with post request rather than get method @Tommy Yeh